# How to interrupt exec and kill child processes

Tags: php, signals, exec, pcntl

I'm trying to invoke a long-running shell command inside a PHP CLI script with `exec()`. But I can't for the life of me figure out how to interrupt the PHP script and kill the spawned child process(s). It seems like as soon as I call `exec()`, my signal handler is ignored. The following code works as I would expect; if I send SIGTERM to the process, it echoes `SIGTERM` and exits immediately.

```
<?php
  declare(ticks = 1);

  function sig_handler($signo) {
    switch ($signo) {
      case SIGTERM:
        echo 'SIGTERM' . PHP_EOL;
        flush();
        break;
      default:
    }
  }

  pcntl_signal(SIGTERM, 'sig_handler', false);

  sleep(60);
?>
```

However, if I replace `sleep(60);` with `exec('sleep 60');`, I don't reach my signal handler until the sleep finishes. I have two questions:

1. How can I get signals to work with `exec` (or `shell_exec` or `proc_open`)?
2. Upon trapping a signal, how can I kill any child processes spawned by `exec`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) does say that:

> If a program is started with this function, in order for it to continue running in the background, the output of the program must be redirected to a file or another output stream. **Failing to do so will cause PHP to hang until the execution of the program ends.**

(Emphasis mine.) I guess the hanging applies to signal handlers, too.

To be able to control the child process it looks like you have to execute them in the old-fashioned way,  with fork+exec:

```
switch ($pid = pcntl_fork()) {
  case -1: // failed to create process
     die('Fork failed');
  case 0: // child
     pcntl_exec($path,$args);
     die('Exec failed');
}
```

Once the parent process has the child's process id in `$pid`, it could send SIGINT to the child with `posix_kill($pid, SIGINT)`.

Update: apparently you could also use `proc_open` and `proc_terminate`.

Comment: Doh! I even knew about exec() hanging, already ran into that in a different context. I tried the pcntl_fork, pcntl_exec method yesterday and about a thousand other permutations but just couldn't get it to work in my project. But after seeing your answer I created a simple test script and it worked like a charm. The only problem now is, after I send a signal to my child process, it becomes a zombie.

Comment: I solved the zombie child process by adding SIGCHLD to my signal handler and running pcntl_waitpid(0, $status) (also in the signal handler). So, if the parent receives SIGTERM, it stops waiting for the child and sends SIGTERM; when the child exits, it sends SIGCHLD to the parent and gets cleaned up...everyone is happy.